# webscrapping using python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

i create a small program in python using selenium module.

here is my code :

```
while True:
try:
    btnOptions = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/...."))).click()
    firstElement = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Click']")
    if not firstElement:
        tnTrash = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Move']"))).click()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                                                    "/html/body/..."))).click()
    else:
        firstElement.click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    break
```

the loop should do:

Step 1 :
find the BtnOption button ->
btnOptions = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/...."))).click()

the menu opens, in this menu there can be either elemnt1 or element2; never both at the same time.
for example,

```
element1 is : 
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[text()='element1']"))
element2 is : 
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[text()='element2']"))
```

step 2 :
if element 1 is found, then we click on it and restart the loop at the beginning.
if it is element2 that is found, click on it and restart the loop at the beginning.

when it's a post to delete, element1 appears in the drop-down menu, if it's a profile photo, element2 appears in the drop-down menu.

for the moment my program continues as long as it finds element1, if it is element2 which is present it stops with an error telling me that element1 was not found

I thought of that but it still doesn't work :

```
while True:
try:
    btnOptions = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div..."))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//*[text()='move to trash']"))).click() or WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//*[text()='Do not show in profile']"))).click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "my_element"))).click()
except:
    while True:
        try:
            btnOptions = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div["
                                                                                                   "1]/div/div["
                                                                                                   "1]/div/div["
                                                                                                   "5]/div/div/div["
                                                                                                   "3]/div/div/div["
                                                                                                   "1]/div["
                                                                                                   "1]/div/div/div["
                                                                                                   "4]/div[2]/div/div["
                                                                                                   "2]/div[3]/div["
                                                                                                   "3]/div/div/div/div"
                                                                                                   "/div/div/div/div/div"
                                                                                                   "/div/div["
                                                                                                   "8]/div/div/div["
                                                                                                   "2]/div/div["
                                                                                                   "3]/div/div")))
            time.sleep(2)
            btnOptions.click()
            time.sleep(2)
            btnTrash = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Déplacer "
                                                                                                 "dans la corbeille']")))
            time.sleep(1)
            btnTrash.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            btn_move = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                                                                       "/html/body/div[1]/div/div["
                                                                                       "1]/div/div[ "
                                                                                       "6]/div/div/div[1]/div/div["
                                                                                       "2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div["
                                                                                       "3]/div/div/div/div[1]")))
            time.sleep(1)
            btn_move.click()
            time.sleep(7)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            break
```

You try to click your element, if ok then code will continue after the except block, if click fails means element was not there, so it will run your expected code into except block

Comment: thank you its helping :) i'm trying right now

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to validate element existence is to use `find_elements` method since in this case there will no exception thrown in case of no element found.
There are several issues should be improved in your code:

1. Since you are clicking elements here you should use `element_to_be_clickable` `expected_conditions`, not `presence_of_element_located`.
2. No need to add sleeps between actions when you are using `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions`.
   3)You can perform `click()` directly on the returned web element object, no need to put it into temporary variable.
   4)Your locators should be improved, but I can't help here since I don't know what page are you working on.

So, your code can be like the following:

```py
first_element_list = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"the_element_locator")
if first_element_list:
    first_element_list[0].click()
else:
    while True:
        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[5]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[8]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div"))).click()
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Déplacer dans la corbeille']"))).click()
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,  "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[6]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]"))).click()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            break
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this learning session, very interesting.

Comment: i tried to improve a bit my code, but it s not working as expected yet. i need it to check if element1 is located, if yes do some action, if not ignore and search for elemnt2, if located do some actions. for now all i try is not good because it stop one time because element1 is not located or element2 etc etc

Comment: II edited the post with the new code.
the loop does not repeat itself yet, I do not understand where is my mistake

Comment: Can you share a link to the page you working on? We need that for minimal debugging.

Comment: it is facebook on my own personal account

Comment: I see. So, how can I help without ability to perform minimal debugging?

Comment: i think it will work with any account, if you got one you can try ?

Comment: i need the program to click on the drop-down menu of my publication then depending on whether it finds the elemet1 or element 2, whether it does this or that action and start again the loop.. :/ i'm stuck

Comment: Maybe. Please add in the question clear description what exactly you trying to do there so we can reproduce that on other FB accounts

Comment: I hope it's clearer now?

Comment: Absolutely not. You did not describe the specific scenario. All you wrote is: I do something on my FB and it doesn't work for me. OK, so? What exactly you trying to do there? To find some element? What element? What is the flow?

Comment: edited, thank you for helping me and your patience, my English is not so good sorry

Comment: My English is not mother tongue too, it's OK :) But your scenario is still not clear at all. `Step 1 : find the BtnOption button -> btnOptions = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/...."))).click()` what **exactly** button is it? where is it? how can I access it and where?

Comment: The same about all the rest

Comment: when you go to your profile, you have all your publications, on each publication there is a button represented by three points, in the upper right corner of each publication
this is what I call the option button.
it's a small drop-down menu that allows you to act on this or that publication.
some publications may be "deleted" and others may be "not displayed in the profile"

Comment: I'm sorry, I had no time today and almost sure will not be able to do that tomorrow too. Maybe try asking this question again. Add the full explanations of what you trying to do there. I hope someone will be able to help with this, it's not so difficult issue.

Comment: thats fine, i will try again, thanks